# Java: Does type-casting cause an operation during run-time?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)
states that

> A specific conversion from type S to type T allows an expression of type S to be treated at compile time as if it had type T instead. **In some cases this will require a corresponding action at run time to check the validity of the conversion or to translate the run-time value of the expression into a form appropriate for the new type T.**

[The list of JVM instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.checkcast) contains

> ***checkcast***
>
> Operation
>
> Check whether object is of given type

```
Object o = new String();
String s =
(String)//what does the JVM do?
o;
```

Since the description states that checkcast throws a **ClassCastException** on failure and checks if an **objectref** can be cast to a given type, I guessed that this may be the instruction executed during run-time if I downcast in my code.

First of all {1} : Is this assumption correct?

And if so:

```
Object o = (Object)//What do I do now?
new String();
```

{2} Is this also the case for implicit or explicit upcasting?

{3} How much runtime penalty does this instruction incur in the scale of other micro-optimizations?

In contrast to for example moving a field containing an object reference to a local function variable for quicker access time, or other kinds of micro-optimization how much performance does checkcast require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact details do, of course, depend upon the architecture.

Casting of primitives and objects are largely unrelated.

For primitive conversions there may be a requirement to move values between integer and floating point registers or for sign extension, but these are generally extremely fast operations dwarfed by memory access times.

Objects are different.

The bytecode->native compiler may be able to prove that a conversion of an object always succeeds, so no action occurs at runtime.

Typically there is virtually no performance overhead from a successful `checkcast`. There's various optimisations (for which there may be a reasonable guide somewhere). Most of the optimisations are necessary even if you just wanted to call a virtual method efficiently. Further, generics are just a "compiler fiction" so implicit casts are very common. In the olden days abstract classes may have been preferred over interfaces because of simpler virtual method dispatch, but nobody has cared for twenty years.

In your example code, the cast may be shown to always succeed. Otherwise, as `String` is final, the only check necessary is that the type information in the object header is correct. No further memory accesses are required.

Comment: Pretty much what I asked for. But what are the optimisations you are writing about? Do you mean optimizing away the necessity of checkcast? And why do abstract classes have simpler virtual method dispatch than interfaces? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user10385242 Classes only have single inheritance. This means you can number method, starting with a base class. Finding the method address then just becomes a matter of loading a fixed offset into the class data structure which each object header has a pointer to. Interfaces are more complicated. I don't have a good reference to the optimisations typically made. For sometime HotSpot has been able to, for example, inline two different possible implementations of a virtual method (originally for NIO buffers).

Comment: So if I understood correctly, abstract classes, because java only has single inheritance, can number methods with a fixed offset, which is retained in every class that inherits from it. This then allows any derived class to find the same exact method by loading the same offset into the class data structure. And inlining different method implementations would then allow to skip a checkcast if this method is the only goal of the cast. Is that right?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline the instructions about comment formatting don t seem to work, hmmm... maybe that will do